# Influence graph

Tags: graphs, terminology

So, I have a graph **G** with a property called **influence**. The property sounds like : **∀v ∈ V (G)**, if **v** is influenced then he changes his opinion **ov** which he has on **¬ov**, and any neighbor **w** of **v** in **G   (w∈NG(v))** changes his opinion too(from **ow** to **¬ow**).
Also, if all nodes of graph have the same opinion **o**, then there exists a set **S** which discovers that all nodes have the opinion **¬o**.

I heard that this a well known problem, found in different online games but i don't know exactly the name.. could anyone help me?

Comment: Welcome to Computer Science! The title you have chosen is not well suited to representing your question. Please take some time to improve it; we have collected some advice [here](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/a/815/). Thank you!

Comment: Which problem? You have not specified a problem.

Comment: I've deleted the second, completely unrelated question. You can post it separately.

Comment: "Also, if all nodes of graph have the same opinion o, then there exists a set S which discovers that all nodes have the opinion ¬o."

I'm not quite sure if I understand what this means. Can you expand on this a bit?

It seems like if your graph is connected, then changing one person's opinion will immediately flip the opinion of the graph completely (by transitivity of the influence that you have outlined). Is this intended?

Comment: You influence once a node, and then another node, and so on (the order doesn't matter) you get to the point that S contain all the same opinion for nodes **¬o**

Comment: And the graph isn't connected(not every node is neighbor with other)

Comment: I think I see what you mean. You are just looking for the connected components of $G$. In particular, if you give a strict ordering to each vertex of your graph, then the set $S = \{v \mid v \text{ is the smallest vertex in some component of }G\}$ satisfies your needs. Visually, you can look at the big picture and think about your graph in terms of a set of clusters of its connected components; each of these clusters is then labelled by its minimal term. 

Here, the assumption is that the graph is undirected.

Comment: If on the other hand, your graph is directed, then the problem is a bit more tricky. Fortunately, there's still a general framework for this problem and you can think about it in terms of "independence". Intuitively, given two vertices $v$ and $u$, then we say that they are "independence", or $v \perp u$, if there are no paths between $u \to^* v$ and no paths between $v \to^* u$. Now, there's a simple property of this system, which I will refer to as exchange. Exchange says that given two sets of independent vertices $A$ and $B$, if $|B| = |A| + 1$, then (continued in the next comment)

Comment: then there's some element $x$ in $B$ such that $A \cup \{x\}$ remains independent. While it's not exactly a trivial property to prove, the intuition is that for each element $u \in A$ and $x \in B$, either they lie on the same maximal chain ($u \not\perp x$), or they don't ($u \perp x$).

Given this, you can formulate your problem in terms of finding a maximal independent set. The exchange property also guarantees that this local maximality gives a global maximum as well. Once you have a maximum independent set, you just have to find the "initial" term of the maximal chain foreach vertex.